# Custom Button doesn't show its content properly

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Okay, I made a Custom Button in my .xaml file in my WPF Project, I've done everything, but the Content isn't showing... The C# code is default, nothing changed, but here's my .xaml code:

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="TESTING" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197,158,0,0" Height="30" Width="120">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Height="30" Width="120" Stretch="Fill">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_normal.png"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_hover.png"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_disabled.png"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Comment: When you say the Content doesn't show is it the string "TESTING' that you are expecting to see?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't show, really. :/ idk why..

Comment: What doesn't show? "TESTING"? Can you explain your issue clearly?

Comment: The Content "TESTING" doesn't show as the primary text of a button. Whatever I type in Content, I only see the image, no text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace the ControlTemplate of a control you replace all of its visual functionality, including the part that displays the Content property. If you want a button that shows an image and whatever is in the Content property you are pretty close, just add a ContentPresenter into your template like so:

```
<Button Name="TestButton" Content="TESTING" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="197,158,0,0" Height="30" Width="120">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                <Image Height="30" Width="120" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_normal.png"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_hover.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/btn_primary_disabled.png"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Also note the specification of the TargetType in the ControlTemplate, this is important.

Comment: You don't need a binding on the ContentPresenter. See the example at the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Everything else looks good

Comment: I suspect that the ContentPresenter is being clipped because of the fixed height of the button. Try replacing the StackPanel with a Grid and the text should appear on top of the image - I've updated my example

Comment: Works... perfectly. HOW DID I MISS THIS?! Thank you! :D